# Multi level timeline

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I want to write my internship report with it.

I have briefly summarized the history of the company and I want to use something visual.

I tried to reproduce this (done with a WYSIWYG editor):

[image: example]

I'm sure something beautiful can be done with Tikz but I have absolutely no idea on how to use it.

So I tried to do this timeline by creating a table, but the result is not so great. the text is doing some weird things and the images are not centered verticaly, also I can't make the last image bigger because my column size is fixed.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.33\textwidth} p{0.33\textwidth} p{0.33\textwidth}}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{hydravion} & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{stato} & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{sudaviation}\\
1938: naissance de la société SNCASE (Société nationale de construction aéronautique du sud-est). & 1943: le premier appareil à voilure tournante voit le jour à Marignane. 1956: la SNCASE se transforme en SUD-EST-AVIATION. & 1957: SUD-EST-AVIATION se transforme en SUD-AVIATION\\
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{snias} & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{aerospatiale} & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{eurocopter}\\
1970: SUD-AVIATION, NORD-AVIATION, SEREB fusionnent et donnent naissance à la SNIAS (Société Nationale industrielle aérospatiale). & 1984: la SNIAS devient AEROSPATIALE. Son activité est concentrée dans les domaines de l'aéronautique, de l'espace, ainsi que de l'étude et la production d'avions et d'hélicoptères & 1992: La division "hélicoptère" de l'entreprise Aerospatiale s'unit avec l'hélicoptériste allemand, MBB, pour donner naissance à Eurocopter. 1998: Eurocopter devient Eurocopter EADS company en fusionnant avec le groupe espagnol CASA.\\
& \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{airbushelicopters} & \\
& 2014: le groupe tourne une page de son histoire et se renomme Airbus Helicopters &
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here it what is does:

[image]

Can you give me some hints to improve my design ?

Comment: I do not understand, why your text look so ... ugly(sorry)!? The `o` and `a` is too big, `n` and `N` too small... everything is jumping up and down.

Comment: I edited my MWE to include what you were asking for. Yeah the text does weird things, but that might be because I had to zoom out the pdf preview to like 75% to take the screenshot

Comment: Do you have `cm-super` installed? If not, you might be getting metafont fonts. Your PDF viewer can tell you which fonts you are using and what kind they are. Or you can use `pdffonts` on a Unix-like system, at least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly a beginning? This uses TikZ to lay things out and to draw the text box frames and arrows. Obviously there are other ways but this is quite flexible and powerful if you want to make it fancier or change it as you develop it.

[image: history in TikZ]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      my text/.style={rounded corners=2pt, text width=50mm, font=\sffamily, draw=blue!20!black!50, line width=.5pt, align=left},
      my arrow/.style={rounded corners=2pt, draw=blue!20!cyan, line width=2.5mm, -{Triangle[]}},
    ]

    \node (b1) [my text] {1938: naissance de la société SNCASE (Société nationale de construction aéronautique du sud-est).};
    \node (b2) [right=5mm of b1, my text] {1943: le premier appareil à voilure tournante voit le jour à Marignane.\\1956: la SNCASE se transforme en SUD-EST-AVIATION.};
    \node (b3) [right=5mm of b2, my text] {1957: SUD-EST-AVIATION se transforme en SUD-AVIATION};

    \node (a2) [above=5mm of b2] {\includegraphics[width=30mm]{stato}};
    \node (a1) [left=25mm of a2] {\includegraphics[width=30mm]{hydravion}};
    \node (a3) [right=25mm of a2] {\includegraphics[width=30mm]{sudaviation}};

    \node (c1) [below=25mm of b1] {\includegraphics[width=30mm]{snias}};
    \node (c2) [right=25mm of c1] {\includegraphics[width=30mm]{aerospatiale}};
    \node (c3) [right=25mm of c2] {\includegraphics[width=30mm]{eurocopter}};

    \node (d3) [below=5mm of c3, my text] {1992: La division ``hélicoptère'' de l'entreprise Aerospatiale s'unit avec l'hélicoptériste allemand, MBB, pour donner naissance à Eurocopter.\\1998: Eurocopter devient Eurocopter EADS company en fusionnant avec le groupe espagnol CASA.};
    \node (d2) [left=5mm of d3, my text] {1984: la SNIAS devient AEROSPATIALE. Son activité est concentrée dans les domaines de l'aéronautique, de l'espace, ainsi que de l'étude et la production d'avions et d'hélicoptères};
    \node (d1) [left=5mm of d2, my text] {1970: SUD-AVIATION, NORD-AVIATION, SEREB fusionnent et donnent naissance à la SNIAS (Société Nationale industrielle aérospatiale).};

    \node (e) [below=25mm of d2] {\includegraphics[width=120mm]{airbushelicopters}};

    \node (f) [below=5mm of e, my text] {2014: le groupe tourne une page de son histoire et se renomme Airbus Helicopters};

    \foreach \i/\j in {a1/a2, a2/a3, c1/c2, c2/c3}
    \path [my arrow] (\i) -- (\j);

    \path [my arrow] (a3) -| ($(b3.south east) + (5mm,0)$) |- ($(b2.south -| b3)!1/2!(c2.north -| b3) + (0,5mm)$) -| (c1);
    \path [my arrow] (c3) -| ($(d3.south east) + (5mm,0)$) |- ($(d3.south -| d3)!1/2!(e.north -| d3) + (0,5mm)$) -| (e);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's nice ! It gives me more understanding on how Tikz works, but how do you know where the first node is going to be placed at first ? Because all your nodes are refering to it directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Tom The first one is at `(0,0)` by default.