# How can I make the diagram similar to the attached in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

[image: Image Required to be made in LaTeX]

I want to make a detailed timeline of life events in a similar fashion of the attached photo, can someone share code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Just perform a google search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com tikz timeline`. One hit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232097/121799

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Based on the tags, i would say you are already aware of TikZ. Have you looked at the manual? It has a great tutorial.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436259/timeline-in-latex/436304; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159835/milestone-graphic-in-tikz/159856#159856  and http://latex-cookbook.net/articles/timeline/ for a start

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.